# Ground clearance

Tags: tires, wheels

Will the ground clearance vary based on the rim diameter?

**Example:** I saw new Hyundai Venue model and it is specified that it has ~190mm for ground clearance, which they might have given for top end variant. The top end variant has 16" wheels and the base model have 15" wheels. Does the ground clearance of the base variant will be lesser than the top variant? If so by how much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rim size has little to do with ground clearance. Manufacturers usually change the tire size (aspect ratio) of the tires so they will continue to have the same rolling diameter between the two. If you have the same rolling diameter, you'll have the same ride height and ground clearance. If they change the ground clearance, you can be assured they'll let you know about it because it becomes a selling point, and they'll usually jack the price to ensure you get the full meaning of their actions.